# How to authenticate in AWS SDK from segment?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, segment-analytics

I'm trying to call some AWS services from my segment function. To do that, I need to set the credentials for AWS, but I cannot find the way.

As you can see in the [segment documentation](https://segment.com/docs/connections/functions/environment/), `AWS` is available. The problems are:

- I cannot use credential file (I only have one file in the segment funcion and cannot add more)
- I cannot use environment variables

I have also tried the following:

```
AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId = "-";
AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey = "-";
```

That works locally with version `2.949.0` but not with `v2.488.0` (the one provided by segment).

Any idea how can I authenticate? I have not found a way to authenticate using javascript code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I'm configuring my AWS credentials using

```
AWS.config.update({
  region: 'us-east-1',
  accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
});
```

For example, to use S3 bucket

```js
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk';

    AWS.config.update({
      region: 'us-east-1',
      accessKeyId: 'ACCESS_KEY',
      secretAccessKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
    });


const s3 = new AWS.S3();

// and do some manipulations with s3
```

I'm not used the segment, but I guess it should work.

Comment: If I use that way I get a 403.

Comment: From where you are receiving 403?

Comment: From my local environment.

Comment: I mean did you got it from the AWS calls? Can you please provide more details and how did you use it?

Comment: That actually works from the segment environment.